# Description Attribute does not available in DNX Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

When I used [Description] Attribute on enum, I get this error: Description Attribute does not available in DNX Core 5.0. How can I set Description attribute for this case?

Comment: Have you tried the Display attribute `[Display(Name = "Email", Description = "Foo")]`?